# Get-ChildItem using multiple paths, and retrieve all files that matches and their path - only the server name

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I build a script that retrieve all files form specific paths that match a name,
and also the path that the files are in.

I want only to get the file name and the server name (Server-1, Server-2 etc..),
and not all the path (\Server-1\test\Desktop\ etc..).

How can I do it?

Thank you

This is the script that I have so far:

```
$filename= Read-Host "Please Enter The file Name Or Part Of It"
$path="\\SERVER-1\test\Desktop\test"
$path2="\\SERVER-2\test\Desktop\test"
$path3="\\SERVER-3\test\Desktop\test"


foreach($path in $path){
Get-ChildItem -Path $path,$path2,$path3 | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*$filename*"} | Format-List Name -GroupBy DirectoryName
}
```

Comment: Use string methods : $paths = ("\\SERVER-1\test\Desktop\test","\\SERVER-2\test\Desktop\test","\\SERVER-3\test\Desktop\test");
foreach($path in $paths)
{
   $index = $path.IndexOf('\', 2);
   $server = $path.Substring(2, $index - 2);
   Write-Host $server;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Get-ChildItem can take an array of paths, there is no need for a foreach loop.

Here's one aproach:

```
$filename = Read-Host "Please Enter The file Name Or Part Of It"
$paths = '\\SERVER-1\test\Desktop\test', '\\SERVER-2\test\Desktop\test', '\\SERVER-3\test\Desktop\test'
Get-ChildItem -Path $paths -Filter "*$filename*" -File | 
Select-Object @{Name = 'Server'; Expression = {$_.DirectoryName.Trim("\").Split("\")[0]}}, Name
```